# Can't answer a highly active question even though I meet the reputation requirement

Tags: support, reputation, protected-posts

I seem to have found either a bug or an outdated message as can be seen in the below screenshot for me on this question: [Google Chrome Dictionary Location](https://superuser.com/questions/280181/google-chrome-dictionary-location)

> Highly active question. Earn **10** reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

I am currently on a whopping 63 rep, so not 100% what is going on here.

[image]

Comment: Its 10 reputation earned on this site. I'll need to poke further but, 63 rep seems to indicate you have *negative* reputation after association bonus, I'm not sure exactly how its calculated in those cases but I'd guess that would be it.

Comment: @Aibobot Yes I did receive the 100 rep association bonus coming in from Stack. Yes you are correct I did offer a 50rep bounty a long time ago, so maybe that is where a negative rep score would come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/295232):

> ### Who can answer a protected question?
>
> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check<sup>2</sup>**, so users with the association bonus require 110 reputation to answer protected questions. In other words, all users must have earned 10 or more reputation *on that specific site* to answer a protected question.

One could argue you *did* earn [12 reputation](https://superuser.com/users/709080/zze?tab=reputation) on Super User so far, but that's not how the check currently works: this way, it's consistent with the principle that you lose privileges if you lose reputation.

Comment: Which makes me wonder how much more reputation he needs to actually answer the question

Comment: @Aibobot 110-63=47

Comment: You have only earned 10 reputation but lost 3 after you don’t consider the 100 reputation.  All you need to do is answer a single question that isn’t protected with a high quality answer.  Your example question has several low quality answers that have already been deleted.